# How to write a sigmoid curve using excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create an s curve. The image below is an example of my attempt.

[image: excel attempt]

As you can see it seems to be only the curve up (formula shown) - can someone please help?

Comment: Your picture suggests that you are plotting line 1 against line 3. The reader cannot see if data in row 2 has any meaning at all. You might consider telling the reader what you expect to see - what you got is well visible on the diagramm.

Comment: Row 1: the number of steps between the Start and End value (11 is an arbitrary number of steps, it might be more or less)
Row 2: my attempt at the s curve forumla
Row 3: start value + (end value * row 2 formula result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sigmoid Curve (or S Curve) there is no "average" or "max" used.

The formula is like this :
Logistic Curve `f(x) = 1/(1+e^{-x})`

**Drawing** that requires **Negative , Zero & Positive** value for x.

Hence in Row 1 : C1 to M1 , put in the values `-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5`
In Row 2 : `C2=1/(1+EXP(-C1))` , `D2=1/(1+EXP(-D1))` (COPY-PASTE till M2)

You should get some values like this :

```
Row 1 : [   -5 ,   -4 ,   -3 ,   -2 ,   -1 ,    0 ,    1 ,    2 ,    3 ,    4 ,    5 ]  
Row 2 : [0.0067,0.0179,0.0474,0.1192,0.2689,0.5000,0.7310,0.8807,0.9525,0.9820,0.9933]
```

Now **Plot** Row 1 against Row 2 ( C1:M1 against C2:M2 ) to get the Logistic Curve.

[image: logistic Curve]

You can check more about [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) & [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to generate that with variations.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the comment you wrote... "Drawing that requires Negative , Zero & Positive value for x" because that really helped to explain it more than a lengthy google search did! Cheers!